# How do I make the leaderboard display the names instead of "None" using json in Python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

basically, I have a command that tells me the leaderboard for the levelling system in a Discord server, however it displays "None" instead of the name of the users in the leaderboard. I've looked all over the internet but I can't seem to find a solution for it. Does anyone know how to fix it so that it displays the usernames instead?

````
async def leaderboard(ctx, x=10):
  with open('level.json', 'r') as f:
    
    users = json.load(f)
    
  leaderboard = {}
  total=[]
  
  for user in list(users[str(ctx.guild.id)]):
    name = str(user)
    total_amt = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user)]['experience']
    leaderboard[total_amt] = name
    total.append(total_amt)
    

  total = sorted(total,reverse=True)
  

  em = discord.Embed(
    title = f'Top {x} people in {ctx.guild.name}',
    description = 'The highest level people on this server'
  )
  
  index = 1
  for amt in total:
    id_ = leaderboard[amt]
    member = bot.get_user(id_)
    
    
    em.add_field(name = f'{index}: {member}', value = f'{amt}', inline=False)
    
    
    if index == x:
      break
    else:
      index += 1
      
  await ctx.send(embed = em)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case if you use `bot.get_user()` it will not cache member until u have intents.members permission. So in this case you should you `await bot.fetch_user()`